# What does const counts: { [c: string]: boolean } = {} mean?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I've got the exercise from a mentor:

> Determine if a word or phrase is an isogram.
>
> An isogram (also known as a "nonpattern word") is a word or phrase without a repeating letter, however spaces and hyphens are allowed to appear multiple times.
>
> Examples of isograms:
>
> ```
> lumberjacks
> background
> downstream
> six-year-old
> ```
>
> The word isograms, however, is not an isogram, because the s repeats.

to describe what this peace of code means. Everything is fine but I did not understand the meaning of the fourth line.

```
    export default class Isogram {
      public static isIsogram(input: string): boolean {
        const chars = [...input.toLowerCase()]
        const counts: { [c: string]: boolean } = {}

        for (const char of chars) {
          if (!this.isLetter(char)) {
            continue
          }

          if (counts[char] !== undefined) {
            return false
          }

          counts[char] = true
        }

        return true
      }

      private static isLetter(char: string): boolean {
        return char.toUpperCase() !== char.toLowerCase()
      }
    }
```

Comment: `const counts = {};` is simple. The rest is the type declaration - check the TypeScript handbook!

Comment: As an aside, type `{ [c: string]: boolean }` can be declared with the pre-existing `Record` type as `Record<string, boolean>`, and simply means an object with `string` keys and `boolean` values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called an [index type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) in TypeScript, and allows you to use dynamic property names.

For your example:

```
const counts: { [c: string]: boolean } = {}
```

The index type signature signifies that the `counts` variable will refer to an object with `string` keys and `boolean` values. In this specific case, the `counts` variable is initialized with an empty object (`{}`).

The object below, for example, will conform to the type described above:

```
{
  'c': true,
  'a': false,
  'r': true
}
```